# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync throws TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync and the POST is never sent. I'm monitoring it with wireshark and nothing goes out.

I feel something is deadlocking in here but can't figure out what. I've read [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) guide and followed it but still nothing. I've tried both ConfigureAwait(false), async, await, creating a new task for the async method, but the call is never returned and the post is never made.

```
public class RequestDespacho
    { 
    /* 
         several public properties
    */
    public async void MakeRequest()
            {
                try
                {                        
                var response = await Requester.MakePost("CreateTicket/", this);
                    switch (response.StatusCode) //this line is never reached
                    {
                        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                            MessageBox.Show("OK");
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                            MessageBox.Show("Forbidden");
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                            MessageBox.Show("Bad Request");
                            break;
                        case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                            MessageBox.Show("Internal Server Error");
                            break;
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) //taskCanceled exception appears after a while
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }

            }
    }
public static class Requester
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client;

        static Requester()
        {
            client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.2.4.29:1234/"),
                DefaultRequestHeaders = {{"x-auth_token", "token1"}},
                Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15)
            };
        }
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakePost(string dir, object data)
        {
            return await client.PostAsJsonAsync(dir, data);
        }
    }
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var image = File.ReadAllBytes(@"G:\1.jpg");
            RequestDespacho req = new RequestDespacho("Av. Monroe 2323", -34.557762, -58.459346, TipoEvento.Merodeo,
                "Palio rojo", image); //my model, doesn't really matter
            await req.MakeRequest();
        }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code that I can see:  1. Creating a new HttpClient for every request.  2. Passing `this` instead of a POCO object.  3. Always returning `true` even in the case of a 400, 403 or 500

Comment: yeah forgot to mention, this is a test form to discover whats going on, I know HttpClient is thread safe and the return value was not used. The only thing I don't understand is what do you mean by a POCO object

Comment: You should have classes that represent the data you need to post (I said POCO, but I guess DTO makes more sense).  This class should only be properties that represent the object that the HTTP endpoint expects. The actual _posting_ of that object should be done in a separate class.

Comment: @maccettura edited, problem continues

Answer (score 0):

It was a network related issue. Conected a wifi usb board and the problem was solved. Still got no idea what blocked the requests...since with postman everything worked but in visual studio it didn't...but the code is allright.